# Angular-translate: the value of {{'HOME_LINK' | translate}} is HOME_LINK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, angular-translate

I am trying to make an internationalization for my current project with angular-translate.js and angular-translate-loader-static-files.js, but now I faced a problem that the translation does not work, so the value of `{{'HOME_LINK' | translate}}` is always `HOME_LINK`. Below is the pertient file:

**app.config.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .constant("idleConfigParams", {"idle": 780, "timeout": 120, "keepalive": 240})
        .config(appConfig);

    /* @ngInject */
    function appConfig($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, KeepaliveProvider, IdleProvider, idleConfigParams, brandProvider, $translateProvider) {

        //Set Brand Name
        brandProvider.setBrandName("ABC");
        brandProvider.setBrandInitial("ABC");

        // enable html5 mode
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/fe/login");

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');

        // Configure Idle settings
        IdleProvider.idle(idleConfigParams.idle);
        IdleProvider.timeout(idleConfigParams.timeout);
        KeepaliveProvider.interval(idleConfigParams.keepalive);

        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage("cn");
        $translateProvider.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'cn'], {
            'en-*': 'en',
            'cn-*': 'cn'
        });

        $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: '/app/languagesLib/',
            suffix: '.json'
        });

    }
})();
```

I am pretty sure is due to the translation files were not loaded, and I am not sure whether the value of prefix is right, giving the follow files structure, anyone who can help me out.

Files structure:

```
app
--account
--activity
--......
--languagesLib
  --cn.json
  --en.json
--layout
  --directives
  --navigation.html
  --footer.html
--app.config.js
--app.controller.js
--app.module.js
--app.run.js
--app.spec.js
```

Comment: what is the contents of your translation file? ie `/app/languagesLib/en.json`

Comment: You don't need to inject the $translate service in your controller unless you plan to use it in your controller. In your html example you are using the translate filter in one list item and the translate directive in another list item. Do they both fail?

Comment: @haxxxton, here is the en.json - {
  "HOME_LINK": "Home",
  "CONSENTS_LINK": "Consents",
  "PROVIDERS_LINK": "Provider"
}

Comment: @o4ohel, yes, they both fail,  one is <span class="nav-label">HOME_LINK</span>, the other is <span class="nav-label" translate="CONSENTS_LINK">CONSENTS_LINK</span>

Comment: @haxxxton, as per the file structure, do you think that I gave the right prefix to $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader ?

Comment: Problem has fixed, thanks guys.